# Cannot open /dev/tty/USB0 with cat after being used with pyserial

Tags: python, linux, cat, pyserial, tty

After having opened my serial port `/dev/tty/USB0`with `pyserial`:

```
>>> ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 57600)
>>> ser.isOpen()
True
>>> ser.close()
>>> ser.isOpen()
False
```

I can no longer read `/dev/ttyUSB0`with the command `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`
usually `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` is a blocking command like `read`, but after the serial port is opened/closed with pyserial, the `cat` command become non blocking, seems like busy ...

Does anybody knows what causes this?

Comment: what do you mean? as long as its closed you should have no problem reading it ... what if you reopen it in python can you still read from it?

Comment: usually `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`is a blocking command like `read`, but after the serial port is opened/closed with pserial, the `cat`command is no longer blocking, seems like busy ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when pyserial opens the tty, it implicitly reconfigure some parameters of the tty for example: `time=0` which set the timeout to 0 second, and  `min=0`, which set the minimum characters to read, etc.

And to restore the default behavior, use the linux command `stty`
`stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 icanon`